# Simplifying this JavaScript-switch

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I would like some advice on how to slim down this switch:

```
switch (lotUser | winningLot) {
        case lotUser === winningLot[0]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[1]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[2]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[3]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[4]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[5]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[6]:
        case lotUser === winningLot[7]:
            console.log("You win!");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("You do not win!");
            break;
    }
```

Instead of

```
case lotUser === winningLot[0]:
```

I wrote the script to be:

```
switch (lotUser | winnendLot) {
    case lotUser === winnendLot[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7]:
        console.log("You win!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("You do not win!");
        break;
}
```

I just don't know if this works the way I want it to work. It needs to check if the generated lotUser is equal to one of the values in an array (winningLot). If the lotUser equals one or more of the values in the winningLot array, it should output "You win!".
Could someone please confirm that my code does the description I gave?

Comment: This does not do what you want it to do. The first script is closer to the correct way to use the switch. It is verbose, but it is the correct way. Also, you are misusing the `|` character. It is a bitwise or operation. So you are actually doing some math between the operators, not choosing one or the other https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: You seam to misunderstand the '|' operator.  This is a _binary_ OR operator.  You will _never_ need this in your code unless you _know_ that you do.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: How would you suggest making it slim and bite size?

Comment: `|` is binary OR.

`0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7` will always be equal to `7` so that there is your first issue.

Comment: @JohannBehrens Your first code is correct (notwithstanding the `|` in the first line). It doesn't get more bite size than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [Array.prototype.indexOf()?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (winnedLot.indexOf(lotUser) !== -1) {
  console.log("Won!");
}
else {
  console.log("Lost!");
}
```

It searches the array for the first occurrence of the value stored in `lotUser` and returns its respective index.

Since you do not need to count the occurrences, this should be the best way.

---

If you want to count them, use a loop:

```
var count = 0;

for (var i=0, len=winnedLot.length; i<len; i++) {
  if (winnedLot[i] === lotUser) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Read into the indexOf() and it is completely clear to me! Thank you for answering :)

Comment: As an additional question, what if I want to log something specific to one position of the array?

Comment: @JohannBehrens Use the second code and just insert `console.log()` or whatever you like in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if(winningLot.indexOf(lotUser) >= 0) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you're using `switch` incorrectly. The value to compare goes in the `switch(...)` part, and the possible values are listed by each `case ...:`

Anyway, that aside, all you want is to check if `lotUser` is in the `winnendLot` array. Easy:

```
// assuming supporting browser:
if( winnendLot.indexOf(lotUser) > -1) console.log("You win!");

// full browser support:
var winner = false, l = winnendLot.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( winnendLot[i] === lotUser) {
        winner = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( winner) console.log("You won!");
```