# How do I get an element from an array.

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I posted this question a few hours ago: [Simplifying this JavaScript-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572388/simplifying-this-javascript-switch)

The additional question I have got is: **How can I get a specific element from an array given a index?** I want to write a custom message fore each of them, with out use of a huge switch:

```
switch (lotUser | winnendLot) {
    case lotUser === winnendLot[0]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[0] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[1]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[1] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[2]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[2] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[3]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[3] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[4]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[4] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[5]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[5] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[6]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[6] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    case lotUser === winnendLot[7]:
        console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[7] + " gewonnen");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("You do not win!");
        break;
}
```

Is it possible to provide different responses with an array index of `lotUser` inside a single case? Maybe I could use if/else.

Comment: Avoid `|` unless your doing bitwise operations, use `||`. Could you provide more code? It looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Dude: I changed the | to || now, it has not made a difference.
I am not sure if I could provide more code than this, it is homework and giving away code might benefit fellow students.

The thing is that this switch-statement apparently does not go into the cases, but heads straight for the default, so it does not evaluate the cases to true.

Comment: I didn't say `||` will fix the problem. I said it's generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572478/2049063) that was given to you, all you have to do is reference the index of the element in the array and use that to show the appropriate message:

```
var winnedIndex = winnedLot.indexOf(lotUser);
if (winnedIndex !== -1) {
  console.log("Je hebt " + naamArtikel[winnedIndex] + " gewonnen");
}
else {
  console.log("You do not win!");
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that I didn't came to think of this.. Thanks A LOT! You have really helped me out :)

Comment: @JohannBehrens Isn't the question how to do with switch? If it isn't, then why is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572388/simplifying-this-javascript-switch ? The question is pretty long and unclear.

Comment: @Dude: I guess I gave the wrong name to this question, you are right about that. The difference is between a common message in case of winning, this question is about a specific message according to the index of the array.

Comment: @JohannBehrens Why didn't you ask about index of array then?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a misunderstanding on the usage of a switch statement.  I would advise you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch  In any case a switch does not seem appropriate in your circumstance anyway. What you want to do is perform a check for every element in the array and print a statement with the array value it when it is true. In which case the following would be the preferred approach.

```
for(var x=0; x<winnendLost.length; x++)
{
  if(lotUser === winnendList[x])
    console.log("Je hebt " + winnendList[x] + " gewonnen");
};
```